# Dagger: injecting named Logger?

Tags: logging, dagger, dagger-2

I have some sort of analytics wrapper that I have to create an instance for in every class like this:

```
Analytics.create(MyClass.class)
```

This is so the built object can use the class name to write better events.

But it is quite annoying (and mistake prone) to create this object like this for every class, so I thought about using Dagger (or Dagger2) for this.

Is there a way I can inject the current class to an already injected object? Better yet, what is a good approach to have named loggers injected?

Answer (score 0):

[loginject](https://github.com/raner/loginject) has a [dagger example](https://github.com/raner/loginject/blob/master/loginject/loginject-dagger/src/test/java/org/loginject/JavaUtilLoggingLoggerTest.java) of injecting a logger in this kind of way. You could have a look at how they implemented it and use the same approach for your class.

```
import static org.loginject.LogInject.*;
import static org.loginject.LogParameter.*;

@Provides
Logger provideLogger() {
    return loginject(Logger::getLogger,currentClassName()).as(Logger.class);
}
```

PS: I sometimes use a pattern like this:

```
public interface WithLogger {
    default Logger logger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    }
}
```